# Supernatural Territories

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, hunter-the-vigil

So it's pretty obvious to me, that two Werewolf Pack Territories wouldn't overlap, but what about a Vampire territory, and Werewolf territory? Is it possible that they don't actually know the other is present? Mix'n Match your Supernaturals. What if we're talking Changelings and Vampires, or Geists and Demons, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
most territories are not in anyway supernaturally or physically marked.
The exception is werewolf territories, that have spiritual marks visible. But you basically have to be a werewolf or a spirit to see them.

- Most supernaturals don't take as strong a idea of physical territory as werewolves do. For obvious reasons.
- A Changeling Freehold is not "All changelings in this city" it is "All changelings who are sworn to our courts".

  - Two freeholds can exist in one city. This often means a state of Warfare See some examples of this in "Swords at Dawn".
- Similar for a Mage counsilium
- Vampires tend to administer domains to various people and subgrouping for purposes of managing freeding.

Most supernatural have vary limited  ability to perceive other supernatural.
Many don't even believe in other supernaturals.

Generally what ever precautions the supernaturals are taken to hide themselves from the mortal authorities will protect them from other supernaturals.

Unless that isn't the story you want to tell.
(Vampire Envoy etc to the Changeling Freehold is such a nice idea, its referenced thoughout much of changeling)

### Exceptions:

- Mages can, if they put the effort in, recognise anyone.
- Changelings mask protects them from anyone who doesn't have powerful ability pierce illusions (So mostly mages, but if you look hard enough most templates can get the ability if they specialise)
- All supernaturals are immune to lunacy, thus they can if they get luck sport a werewolf and remember.
- The Aura Sight ability most templates get, is the best ability to recognise supernaturals.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much the supernatural in question polices their territory and with what method.

A werewolf pack that patrols their rural territory will likely notice that there is a large wolf that seems to be attacking animals and leaving them weak without a scratch (a Gangrel vampire hunting in wolf form).

A Mage that ostensibly controls a neighborhood but really just cares that her Hallow is getting the proper ley energies from the surrounding land might not notice a secret Changeling war, but will definitely notice the Promethean who's slowly forming a Wasteland there.

A Sin-Eater krewe who patrols their neighborhood for ghosts will definitely notice a Vampire nightclub since they can automatically tell that the Kindred are dead when they look at them.

In the LARP chronicle I'm involved in, supernaturals will sometimes get hints of each other's existence and make uneasy treaties regarding territory and borders.